# Send order to delivery service based on order status in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, orders

My orders are automatically sent to the external delivery service. But when the status of the order changes, it is again sent to the external delivery service. How to fix it?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_stock_reduction_based_on_status', 20, 4 );
function order_stock_reduction_based_on_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only for 'processing' and 'hold-on' order statuses change
    if ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'hold-on' ) {
        // Checking if this has already been done avoiding reload
        if (get_post_meta($order_id, 'delivery_order_id', true)) {
            return; // Exit if already processed
        }
    }

    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    // Send data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?new_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

    // Output
    if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success' && isset($decoded['order_id']) && !empty($decoded['order_id']) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', esc_attr( $decoded['order_id'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested setting a post meta field to store if the order has been sent to the external delivery service? You could then check that value and return if it's true. Like you do already for _Exit if already processed_.

Comment: Yes, this field have value, but still when you change the status of the order in the admin panel, the order resends.

Comment: And when resubmitted, this field is overwritten by the new one.

Comment: What field do you refer to?

Comment: delivery_order_id

Comment: Any idea? Theoretically, this should not happen. But maybe there are some unknown moments with `$new_status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple I think. The First `IF` statement should be closed at the end instead, to avoid this repetition issue.

So your code will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_stock_reduction_based_on_status', 20, 4 );
function order_stock_reduction_based_on_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only for 'processing' and 'hold-on' order statuses change
    if ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'hold-on' ) {
        // Checking if this has already been done avoiding reload
        $delivery_order_id = get_post_meta($order_id, 'delivery_order_id', true);
        if ( ! empty( $delivery_order_id  ) ) {
            return; // Exit if already processed
        }

        $order_data = $order->get_data();

        // Send data
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?new_order");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

        // Output
        if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success' && isset($decoded['order_id']) && !empty($decoded['order_id']) ){
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', esc_attr( $decoded['order_id'] ) );
        }
    } // <==  <==  <==  <==  Closing bracket HERE
}
```

It should just work fine now (I hope).